# Peskin & Schroeder Chap 7.1: Two-point correlation function in Field Strength renormalization

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, correlation-functions, propagator

I have some simple questions. I was going through Peskin & Schoeder Introduction to QFT, trying to understand the two-point correlation function on interacting theory (Chapter 7.1) for the case $x^0>y^0$,

$$
\langle{\Omega}|\phi(x)\phi(y)|{\Omega}\rangle = \sum_\lambda \int \dfrac{d^4p}{(2\pi)^4}\dfrac{i}{p^2-m_\lambda^2+i\epsilon}e^{-ip\cdot(x-y)}|\langle{\Omega}|\phi(0)|{\lambda_0}\rangle|^2. \tag{ Eq. 7.3}
$$

I'm trying to obtain this equation. From the book, we can insert an identity operator betwen the two fields in $\langle{\Omega}|\phi(x)\phi(y)|{\Omega}\rangle$ and insert the completeness relation,
$$
\mathbb{I}=|{\Omega}\rangle\langle{\Omega}|+\sum_\lambda\int \dfrac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\dfrac{1}{2E_\mathbb{p}}|{\lambda_p}\rangle\langle{\lambda_p}|.
$$
where $|{\lambda_p}\rangle$ is a boost(with momentum $\mathbb{p}$) of $|{\lambda_0}\rangle$, the eigenstate of $H$ with momentum zero. Ignoring the $|{\Omega}\rangle\langle{\Omega}|$ we find

$$
\langle{\Omega}|\phi(x)\phi(y)|{\Omega}\rangle = \sum_\lambda \int \dfrac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^32E_p}\langle{\Omega}|\phi(x)|{\lambda_p}\rangle\langle{\lambda_p}|\phi(y)|{\Omega}\rangle.
$$
Given
$$
\langle{\Omega}|\phi(x)|{\lambda_p}\rangle=\langle{\Omega}|\phi(0)|{\lambda_0}\rangle e^{-ip\cdot x}\mid_{p^0=E_\mathbb{p}},$$

we can substitute the terms inside the integrals, resulting in
$$
\langle{\Omega}|\phi(x)\phi(y)|{\Omega}\rangle = \sum_\lambda \int \dfrac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^32E_p}|\langle{\Omega}|\phi(0)|{\lambda_0}\rangle|^2e^{-ip\cdot(x-y)}.
$$

My questions are: It's not clear for me yet how do I go from $\dfrac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^32E_p}$ to $\dfrac{d^4p}{(2\pi)^4}$. Where did the Feynman propagator comes from?

Comment: Have you tried to use the Residue theorem on $\frac{1}{2E_p}$? Because this is the standard method.

Comment: That solves the problem. Thank you